# What are the main differences between Redis Pub/Sub and Redis Stream?

Tags: database, caching, redis, publish-subscribe

What are the pros and cons of each?
Please advice when to use one and not the other.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

### Data storage

Pub/Sub is a Publisher/Subscriber platform, it's not data storage. Published messages evaporate, regardless if there was any subscriber.

In Redis Streams, stream is a data type, a data structure on its own right. Messages or entries are stored in memory and stay there until commanded to be deleted.

### Sync/Async communication (Push/Pull)

Pub/Sub is synchronous communication (**push** protocol). All parties need to be active at the same time to be able to communicate. Here Redis is a pure synchronous messaging broker.

Redis Streams allow for both synchronous (`XREAD` with `BLOCK` and the special `$` ID is a **push** protocol) and asynchronous communication (regular `XREAD` is a **pull** protocol). `XREAD` with `BLOCK` is like Pub/Sub, but with the ability to resume on disconnection without losing messages.

### Delivery Semantics

Pub/Sub is At-most-once, i.e. "fire and forget".

Redis Streams allows for both At-most-once or At-least-once (explicit acknowledgement sent by the receiver)

### Blocking mode for consumers

Pub/Sub is blocking-mode only. Once subscribed to a channel, the client is put into subscriber mode and it cannot issue commands (except for `[P]SUBSCRIBE`, `[P]UNSUBSCRIBE`, `PING` and `QUIT`), it has become read-only.

Redis Streams allows consumers to read messages in blocking mode or not.

### Fan-out

Pub/Sub is fan-out only. All active clients get all messages.

Redis Streams allows fan-out (with `XREAD`), but also to provide a different subset of messages from the same stream to many clients. This allows scaling message processing, by routing different messages to different workers, in a way that it is not possible that the same message is delivered to multiple consumers. This last scenario is achieved with *consumer groups*.

---

Redis Streams provide many more features, like time-stamps, field-value pairs, ranges, etc. It doesn't mean you should always go for Streams. If your use-case can be achieved with Pub/Sub, it is better for you to use Pub/Sub then. With Streams, you have to care for memory usage.

Comment: Excellent answer! There're two minor problems: 1. since Redis might lose data when it's down, so Redis Stream cannot guarantee at-least-once. 2. when client subscribes to a channel, it can still issue some commands, such as UNSUBSCRIBE, PING, QUIT...

Comment: Thanks for this and the rest of the help that you've been rendering lately here :)

Comment: @MarcusSmith this is about Redis Pub Sub, not about Google Pub Sub

Comment: @LeoMurillo My apologies! I definitely read this as Google Pub/Sub. Probably because my mind was on Google Pub/Sub at the time. I will edit my comment to reflect an alternative suggest for Google Pub/Sub instead of calling your answer incorrect.

Comment: Maybe alternatively look at Google Pub/Sub (as it solves some of the concerns here). 1. data doesn't "just evaporate" even if it hasn't been acknowledged. It does expire after 7 days, good for high-volume communication layer. 2.Google Pub/Sub is At-least-once and has the SLA to ensure that. 3. Google Pub/Sub also has filtering so that subscribers don't get everything. Ultimately Redis is more than a communication layer and offers different options based on your needs, where Google Pub/Sub is a very good communication layer, and just that. See [Google Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub)

Comment: Just as an observation @LeoMurillo, data loss is largely dependent on how Redis is configured.  There are multiple options; AOF, snapshots, Active-Active or master/slave clustering, Redis on flash, etc., that allow you to control data replication to meet the specific tolerance needs of your application.

Comment: @InfoSponge true, yet somewhat orthogonal to the question. Most of those configurations affect replication or durability of keys, not affecting pubsub. For strong durability, worth looking at https://aws.amazon.com/memorydb/

Comment: @LeoMurillo That's a fair point, my comment wasn't actually addressing the original question.  I have no idea what prompted my response, honestly, other than a previous conversation regarding durability in Redis.  I'll pay more attention next time.