# How check if redis channel is already subscribed with StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I have a Windows Service that runs some processes and it must be notify the progress of it on the browser. I am not sure if I am doing something that is good but I just did it:

`Windows Service publish a json on a redis channel called 'web'` -> `An action on ASP.NET MVC application subscribe the 'web' channel and send the json to browser via signalR hub` -> `the browser take it and show the progress`.

I have the following code (it is a helper) to add a channel scope after a publish. It is called from my controller/action:

```
public void Listen(string channel, Action<string, object> action)
{
   var sub = Client.GetSubscriber();

   sub.Subscribe(channel, (c, v) =>
   {
      action(c.ToString(), v.ToString());
   });
}
```

**The problem**: It works as expetected and I get the browser notified. The problem is when the user (on browser) hits F5 or executes the action again. It creates a new channel and I get duplicated messages. If the users executes again it, I started getting 3 messages for each one and so on. I want to avoid it.

**What I have tried**: I tried to use the `IsConnection(channel)` but it always returns `true`. I have tried to `Unsubscribe(channel)` before `Subscribe(channel)` again and it works but I am not sure if i will lost some messages (I am afraid). I do not know how to solve it and avoid getting duplicate subscriptions. Does anyone can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `ConnectionMultiplexer`? See [Using redis pub/sub](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics#using-redis-pubsub).

> ... in the event of connection failure, the ConnectionMultiplexer will
>   handle all the details of re-subscribing to the requested channels

Consider switching from Pub/Sub to Redis Streams. See [What are the main differences between Redis Pub/Sub and Redis Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540563/what-are-the-main-differences-between-redis-pub-sub-and-redis-stream/59541410#59541410)

You can name [groups and clients](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup) with [Consumer Groups](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro#consumer-groups). Therefore you can control it by session, or anything else, or even use something like [fingerprint.js](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) to identify each browser anonymously.

Comment: Yes, the `Client` on my code is a `ConnectionMultiplexer`. Maybe it is create a new subscriber and duplicating the notifications to signalR. That's what I want to avoid and I do not know how. I think the `Pub/Sub` is my case because I just want to send the messages and done.

Comment: How are you starting the `ConnectionMultiplexer`? You should probably create it as singleton in Startup.cs and dependency-inject it to the controller.