# How similar are Redis Pub/Sub and Redis Streams?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to know the difference between Redis Streams and PubSub.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540563/what-are-the-main-differences-between-redis-pub-sub-and-redis-stream

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the main differences between Redis Pub/Sub and Redis Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540563/what-are-the-main-differences-between-redis-pub-sub-and-redis-stream)

Comment: A much detailed answer can be found on this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540563/what-are-the-main-differences-between-redis-pub-sub-and-redis-stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pub/Sub is a Publisher/Subscriber platform, it's not data storage. Published messages evaporate, regardless if there was any subscriber.

In Redis Streams, stream is a data type, a data structure on its own right. Messages or entries are stored in memory and stay there until commanded to be deleted.